# Manage private VPC IP addresses with Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Does any one know if it's possible to manage internal private network addresses (10.0.X.X) using Route 53. As you can imagine, I wouldn't want these names to resolve outside of my VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible at the moment.

If you need this level of control, you'll need to set up your own name servers.

Answer (score 3):

AWS now (finally!!) offers Private Hosted Zones for VPC via Route 53.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-private-hosted-zones.

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time, no, although it's a commonly requested feature on their forums and I'd expect it to eventually make it into R53 as a feature.